# Flask-login can login but can't remember login session

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, remember-me

I'm now learning flask-login now and I'm facing some questions. I can login when my `route` didn't set `@login_required`. While I set `@login_required` and try to redirect after login, it will ask me to login again. Therefore, I'm not sure what occurs about my flask.
Here is my code and my floder structure.

### floder structure

```
Flask_Login
|
|----member
|       |----setting
|       |       |----__init__.py
|       |       |----form.py
|       |       |----model.py
|       |       |----view.py
|       |
|       |----static
|       |----templates
|       |----__init__.py
|       |----sendmail.py
|
|----manage.py
|----config.py
```

### view.py

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = FormLogin()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = UserRegister.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            if user.check_password(form.password.data):
                login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)
                next = request.args.get('next')
                if not next_is_valid(next):
                    return ':-<'
                else:
                    session['username'] = user.username
                    session['login_in'] = True
                    return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash('Wrong')
        else:
            flash('Wrong')
    return render_template('login/login.html', form=form)

def next_is_valid(url): 
    return True


@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return ':->'
```

I'm not sure wherether `session['username'] = user.username` and `session['login_in'] = True` need to be set here and correct set or not, but if they both not be set, flask-login still not working like I expected.

### __init__.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from config import Config
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_login import LoginManager
from datetime import timedelta

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)


mail = Mail(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message = 'Please Logon'
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userID):
    from member.setting.model import UserRegister
    try:
        return UserRegister.query.get(UserRegister.id==userID)
    except:
        return None

from .setting import view
```

### Terminal

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2020 19:51:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2020 19:51:15] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2020 19:51:24] "POST /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2020 19:51:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2020 19:51:24] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = FormLogin()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = UserRegister.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            if user.check_password(form.password.data):
                login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)
                next = request.args.get('next')
                return redirect(next) if next else redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash('Wrong')
        else:
            flash('Wrong')
    return render_template('login/login.html', form=form)
```

Also remove `login_manager.session_protection = "strong"` from init.py

EDIT ::
Make this change : Remove `UserRegister.id==`

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userID):
    from member.setting.model import UserRegister
    try:
        return UserRegister.query.get(userID)
    except:
        return None
```

I hope this works :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution! But it still not work. >_<

Comment: Try the EDIT solution.